# Points on polygon perimeter ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I actually did this a few weeks ago but I can't remember how.

I want to create points on the perimeter of a set of polygons at a specific distance interval. I am using ArcMap.

I could do Polygon Vertices to Points, but that would only give me points on the vertices, which I don't necessarily want. What I want is a regular set of points on the perimeter of the polygons.

This is my base polygons:

[image: Base Polygons]

And this is what I would like to get (the points at regular intervals):

[image: Final Points]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could Use the Densify tool and set as parameter the distance you want between the point.

Then you do a polygon to point processing

Comment: That worked pretty well. I think it's not how I did it the first time around (I can't remember how...) but it works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS Pro you can use the `Generate Points Along Lines` tool in the Data Management Toolbox.