# Generating points along perimeter of circular feature in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, utm, circle

How do I generate equally spaced points on the circumference of a circular feature in ArcMap?

I am currently working on a project where I need 36 equally spaced UTM coordinates that form a silo.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Points on polygon perimeter ArcGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141706/points-on-polygon-perimeter-arcgis?rq=1)

Comment: This is most basic geometry exercise. Use coordinates of the center, radius and 10 Degrees increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check the ArcScript (now called ArcGIS Code Sharing) website for an Esri based solution as there are many free community created tools, often just the thing you need. It took next to no time to find the following tool [Create Points on Lines](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=13c92d8877054b979ac2f69547bd50f1)